# jquery ajax call to rails not returning an array when one record returns

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

The problem I have is that when I make the AJAX call, and there is more than one record, an array is returned and I can call list[0] or whatever to get the first. If I make the same call and receive a single object I get the object back rather than an array of one.

Any ideas how I can handle this?

UPDATE: Used these functions

```
function isArray(obj) {

return (obj.constructor.toString().indexOf("Array") != -1);
```

}

function getArray(obj) {

```
if(obj.constructor.toString().indexOf("Array") != -1){

     return    obj;

} else {

        var myArr = [1];

        myArr[0]=obj;

        return myArr;

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

you could check it with javascript:

```
if ( list.length > 1 ) {
   list[0];
} else {
  list;
}
```

you could also do something like that on server side:

```
@entries = [@entries] unless @entries.is_a?(Array)
```

Comment: That wouldn't work as you are testing the object to see if it's an array which it isin't. In the end I used a function which tested if it was an array and if it wasn't I created one.